# Creating Transfer Function from Data and Applying to Audio Signal

Tags: matlab, function, audio, transfer, convolution

I want to take some audio signal, most likely in stereo, and apply some transfer function to it with the convolution function. I have seen examples here on how to apply transfer functions after obtaining a tfest from two signals, but the tfest data is the same size as the original audio.

I have attempted to navigate MATLAB and become familiar with its interface and syntax by watching the lone Lynda video on MATLAB basics. I have prior programming experience with C# and feel comfortable in Visual Studio, but MATLAB is new to me.

The transfer function is previously obtained, and currently in Excel. The data is in octave bands (63 Hz, 125 Hz, 250 Hz, ... , 8kHz), and will be extrapolated to the spectrum of the input signal (20 Hz - 20 kHz). This will take the form of: (f1, -x1), (f2, -x2), ... ,(fn, -xn), with each data point in the sampled audio having a match with the transfer function.

The function is constant over time. Essentially, I am simulating what something would sound like after passing through a partition.

My thought process tells me this will follow: input audio, transform to frequency domain, apply transfer function, transform back into time domain, and write as WAV.

How would I go about doing this? I understand I did not provide any code, and for this I am sorry. Any resources on the topic are most appreciated. I do not expect a turn-key solution, just some guidance so I can find my way to a correct method.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
function [ out_wav_file ] = TransformSignal( in_waw_file )

% Read input signal
[in_sgn, FS, N] = wavread(in_waw_file);

% If audio file is multiple channel, selec one channel
in_chn = in_sgn(:, 1);

% Transform to frequency domain
% You could use a smaller FFT length but it would cost you quality when
% converting back
fft_in_sgn = abs(fft(in_sgn, length(in_sgn)));

fft_out_sgn = SomeFunction(fft_in_sgn);

out_sgn = ifft(fft_out_sgn);

wavwrite(out_sgn, FS, N, out_wav_file);

end
```

Hope it helps!